# How do I get GNOME 3 to work in Debian Wheezy under VMware?

Tags: debian, gnome3, window-manager, graphics, vmware

I just installed Debian 7.4 in a VMware machine. On first boot, it gave me the following error:

[image: GNOME 3 Failed to load]

```
GNOME 3 Failed to Load

Unfortunately GNOME 3 failed to start properly and started in the
fallback mode.

This most likely means your systeam (graphics hardware or driver) is not
capable of delivering the full GNOME 3 experience.
```

Then, I noticed that 3D acceleration was disabled in my VM settings, so I enabled it and restarted the VM. I still got the same error.

I noticed that the default resolution was 800x600 for some reason, so I increased that and rebooted. This time, I didn't get the error, but I still don't see GNOME 3.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix all this and get GNOME working under VMware?

I am running this on a mid-2011 iMac with an AMD/ATi Radeon HD 6750M 512MB and 16GB of system RAM, so it certainly can't be due to the host system limitations.

Comment: Two things. First, to diagnose the issue, look at `~/.xsession-errors` where `~` is the home directory of the user account you use to log in. Second, my guess is, all you need to do is install guest additions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that  the graphics driver `xserver-xorg-video-vmware` was compiled without 3D acceleration support. This has already been fixed for newer releases, and is in debian jessie.

**The Solution**
Recompile the package with 3D acceleration support

1. install dependencies for VMware Tools
   `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) make gcc`
2. Install the dependencies and build the driver package
   `mkdir tmp && cd tmp`
   `sudo apt-get install libxatracker-dev`
   `sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-video-vmware`
   `sudo apt-get source xserver-xorg-video-vmware -b`
   `sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-video-vmware*.deb`
3. Reboot the machine

If that did not work, try these additional steps:

4. mount the VMware tools cdrom and install VMware Tools
   `sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom`
   `tar xvzf /media/cdrom/VMwareTools-9.6.1-1378637.tar.gz`
   `cd vmware-tools-distrib`
   `sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d`
5. Reboot the machine

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't actually gotten the time to try it out yet, but I will soon and let you know.

Comment: I think a fresh new 7.7 install and enabling 3D as well as 2D acceleration has done the trick, in addition to installing the guest additions.

Comment: First option worked for me on a vanilla install of Debian 7.8.0-i386 on VMWare Workstation 9!