# Blank desktop with Gnome in a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, gnome3

I installed Debian (Wheezy 7.9) as a VM in VirtualBox. But looks like I have a Desktop environment problem:

1. When I right-click on the Desktop, I get nothing (I'm supposed to get a menu).
2. No computer or home icons (even-though they are enabled in Advanced Settings).

BTW, when I enable 3D acceleration for this image on the VBox, the image crashes when logging.

PS:

- Win7 is the OS on which I have VBox installed
- GNOME3 is my Desktop environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's really simple.

1. Yes as according to @AhmedWas, one should *enable 3D acceleration* **before** installing the image. (This will only prevent image crashing)
2. *Applications -> System tools -> Preferences ->Advanced Settings -> Desktop -> and turn on "Have the file manager handle the desktop"*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *enable 3D acceleration* **before** installing the VM image. Otherwise, you will have this kind of problems.

If you can't install a new image, then follow the instructions in the answer of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115912/how-do-i-get-gnome-3-to-work-in-debian-wheezy-under-vmware?rq=1).

Comment: I reinstalled from the beginning and enabled 3D acceleration. This only helped in non-crashing of the image. But, still I can't R-click on Desktop and now icons are visible there.